Measuring resistance to a pot "live" without affecting the circuit?
I've been playing around with op-amps to learn the basics of them (LM741). I made a simple non-inverting amplifier with a potentiometer for the resistor (plus another resistor in series with it) going between the output and negative input. The two resistors I used were equal value, so I would expect to get double the output when the pot was at 0 ohm, and increasing output as the resistance of the pot is increased.
I fed in a 1k 1vpp sinewave and everything is working as expected.
Then what I wanted to do was record various levels of the output vs the pot value, and plot the calculated (expected) output to actual measured output (all peak-peak measurements).
I hooked my digital multimeter up across the pot, and as I increased the pot, the waveform was amplified, however it was not amplified as the expected amount. Here's the plot:

The blue line is the calculated (expected) output, while the orange line is the measured output.
When I disconnected the multimeter, the actual (measured) value was more in line with the expected (calculated) value.
UPDATE 1: Here's the schematic. R1 and R2 are listed at their actual measured values (5.56 and 5.66k respectively). Sorry, I couldn't get pins 1 and 5 to hide in KiCad.

Update 2: Here are the values after disconnecting the multimeter which is reading the resistance of the pot before each measurement. The output is more in line with the expected result:

Would there be any way to measure this pot "live" without affecting the circuit, or do I need to disconnect one lead after making each change to the pot for a new measurement?

Please don't play around with the LM714 if you want to learn the basics of opamps – any (literally, any) other opamp you're likely to buy will behave much more like the opamp in a textbook. The 714 is really just an example of "if someone just invented the integrated circuit on a chip, how bad an opamp can you make and still sell?", not something you would want to learn with :)

Please show us a schematic with values and test points.

… we really need the full schematic, especially how you're loading the opamp output, and how your feedback looks like.

Anything you do to a circuit impacts the circuit.  You cannot measure resistance on a powered circuit.  A DMM in voltmeter mode supplies a voltage and measures current to calculate resistance, in some fashion.  Your meter corrupts your readings.  And using a 741 is like learning to drive on a Model T (and if you have to look that up you know it is bad).

Understood that the meter will affect the circuit, so is there any way (a simple way) measurements could be done without disconnecting the meter each time? I just put a switch in series with one of the meter probes where I could toggle it on and off, and I'd switch the power to the 741 off when measuring the resistance as well. See above updates. BTW, what's the downside of using the 741 on something simple like this?

It's a part that seems to be shambling along solely on the force of examples from old textbooks, from schematics that were designed back when the 741 was the only opamp you could find down at radio shack, and from newer schematics that are derivatives of the old ones. As to your original question, I think a double-ganged potentiometer would be an easy fix. You can get as complicated as you like correlating one side to the other but even just throwing your multimeter on the non-circuit side would give you better performance than what you see here.

Connect the multimeter (ohmmeter) to the other half of the potentiometer with resistance r2 (between terminals 2 and 3) and determine the resistance r1 (between 1 and 2) using the expression r1 = 10k - r2.

Obligatory reasons not to use an LM741 https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/304521/91862

Great idea about putting the meter on the other half of the pot! FYI, the only reason I'm using a 741 is because that was the first one I grabbed out of my op amp bin.

Measure the resistance of the unused end of the pot and subtract that from the total resistance.

Measure resistance from 2 to 3.

The LM741 was designed for use with power supplies in the +/-10V (minimum recommended) to +/-15V (more typical) range. At +/-5V you're at half the minimum recommended power supply voltage and you'll run into limitations if it works at all. Maybe that's the point of this exercise, since all op-amps have limitations.
A 2VAC reading on a multimeter suggests a peak-to-peak voltage closer to 5.6V, which implies that you're actually feeding it with much higher than 1Vp-p.
Multimeters generally read in equivalent RMS assuming a sine wave- since you have a sine wave, the peak-to-peak voltage will be about 2.8x higher. When you compare the oscilloscope and DMM readings you should see this. Some signal generators assume a certain load, depending on how you set them up, and that also can lead to unexpected results.
You are measuring the voltage unconventionally (ie. not wrt ground). The output of the LM741 cannot swing closer than some volts (1 to 5, depending on loading etc) to the power supply rails. Your 'scope trace should show clipping or other distortion, and will give you much more information than the multimeter.
At a total FB resistance of 8.76kΩ, your gain is almost 2.6 so 0.5V input should lead to 1.3V output if the op-amp is behaving ideally.

No clipping on the scope at +/- 5v with 1 Vpp. Clipping occurs at about +/- 3.5V

Too many people mistake 741 as useless even on a single 5V supply but it is capable of producing 2Vpp on a single 5V supply with V+/2 on In+.  But there certainly are better and worse op amps.

As an R&D EE since 1975 for 10 yrs then a Test Engineering Eng/Mgr for 10 yrs later I recognize the testing errors often made while learning electronics.
If you can measure Vpp on your DMM, you are lucky as in my time it was usually measured by peak rectified voltage and converted to RMS assuming a sine wave using \$1/\sqrt(2)\$ scaling.
Resistance measurements require a constant current and then it measures voltage.
If you applied this Ohmmeter test on the side of the pot used in-circuit, it induces a DC offset with increasing R and gain becomes reduced as the signal gets clipped on one side. This forces a DC offset into the output thus reducing the peak voltage less than what you correctly you calculated.  A scope would verify that for you.
Also a simulation. But here I put the simulated 1mA Ohmmeter on the side of the pot not used in-circuit.
Then you can subtract this from the total value for your plot.
For giggles and kicks, Falstad's famous browser simulator has the actual 741 opamp design built in. So I modified it to your circuit gain.  I also reduced the supply to +/-2.5V and because of the Darlington and push-pull outputs, you cannot get a linear swing more than 2.5Vpp centred about zero. That's because of the slightly more than 2 diode drops on either side.
But when using this simulator please keep in mind the default Op Amp is ideal rail-2-rail with no current limit, so for more realism, one inserts an appropriate series R like 220 ohms inside the loop before the feedback from the output.  Since every design IC is different, one can enter that to approximate the output impedance before negative feedback.
Conclusion.
In-circuit testing ICT (for "passive" measurements") is routinely done by very expensive bed-of-nails machines, but always with DC supply off, then Functional Testing is done with the power on for "active parametric results".
Keep in mind resistance measurements use some unknown low constant current just like the "Diode Test" position which actually displays voltage normally to 2V max using something like 0.1 mA so the forward diode voltage should be less than 0.6 regardless of the current rating but if more than 0.6V the current may be more like 1 mA. Not all DMM's are the same.


Note: I'm measuring Vpp on my scope.

Did I err. In how you measured resistance?

No, you just mentioned if I measured Vpp on my DMM.

can you confirm if DMM caused gain error and/or active Op Amp caused error in reading Ohms from loop current. Thankyou. Then use my method and confirm.

How about a double-ganged pot?  Use 1 side for your circuit and the other side for your measurement.
